# How to send goog calander invitation with Customized UI Interface insteadof default google invitation interface

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

Please Help out with my issue,

- I want to override the invitation interface with my own content(HTML).
- I want to replace Below attached UI below (default email template) with My customized design.

  private Event createCalendarEventBuilder(Event event) {
  try {

  ```
        event.setSummary("My Event").setLocation("India")
                      .setDescription("Please join the meeting");

              // Adding event Start date and time
              DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("09-12-2021T01:22:00"));
              EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime)
                      .setTimeZone("18-12-2021T23:22:00");
              event.setStart(start);
              if (userCalendar.getIsItRecurringEvent()) {
                  event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList("{RecurenceRull}"));

                  String recuEndDateTime = userCalendar.getStartDateTime().split("T")[0] + "T"
                          + userCalendar.getEndDateTime().split("T")[1];

                  DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(recuEndDateTime);
                  EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(endDateTime)
                          .setTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
                  event.setEnd(end);

              } 

              // Adding event reminders
              EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                      new EventReminder().setMethod("email")
                              .setMinutes(10),
                      new EventReminder().setMethod("popup")
                              .setMinutes(2)

              };
              Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders().setUseDefault(false)
                      .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
              event.setGuestsCanModify(false);

              event.setReminders(reminders);

              // Adding event attendees
              EventAttendee[] eAttendees;
              if (userCalendar.getAttendees() != null && !userCalendar.getAttendees().isEmpty()) {
                  eAttendees = new EventAttendee[userCalendar.getAttendees().size() + 1];
                  int idx = 1;
                  Iterator<String> attendeesMails = userCalendar.getAttendees().iterator();
                  while (attendeesMails.hasNext()) {
                      String attendeeMail = attendeesMails.next();
                      if (!(attendeeMail.equalsIgnoreCase(userCalendar.getMeetingModerator()))) {
                          eAttendees[idx] = new EventAttendee().setEmail(attendeeMail);
                          idx++;
                      }
                  }
              } else {
                  eAttendees = new EventAttendee[1];
              }
              EventAttendee moderatorAttendee = new EventAttendee();
              moderatorAttendee.setEmail(userCalendar.getMeetingModerator());
              moderatorAttendee.setComment(EventConstants.MOD_COMMENT);
              eAttendees[0] = moderatorAttendee;
              event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(eAttendees));

          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return event;
      }
  ```

Above is My code, Here I want to add Custom(HTML content) notification insteadof below attachment([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwY32.png)).